# How to modify class object parameters in code

Tags: python, class

What I'd like to accomplish is to set `testobj.alpha` to `.5` in the example below:

```
class test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.alpha = 0

d = {'alpha' : .5}
testobj = test()

for i in d:
    testobj.i = d[i] #creates a new class member called 'i' instead of setting alpha to .5
```

As the comment says, in the `for` loop, a new class member called `i` is created, rather than setting the existing `alpha` member to .5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) to set attributes dynamically:

```
for i in d:
    setattr(testobj, i, d[i])
```

or update the internal attribute dictionary directly ([`vars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) will serve as a proxy for the [`__dict__` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=__dict__#object.__dict__)):

```
vars(testobj).update(d) # No (explicit) loop
```

The latter approach will fail if an object doesn't have the `__dict__` attribute (e.g. it was defined with the `__slots__` attribute).